# How select items with same values in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

[image]I'm trying to select many items with same values, but I don't know how do it.

I have two Cards, inside two Containers with Id = 1 and Id = 2,
when I select a container, I use different color in Container to show if is selected or not.

But, in second Card is showing my first selection on first Card. Because I'm using same Id's.

How can I make different selection with same values?

And how can I do that with many Cards?

I did this example to show you easily. Because I'm trying to split my code in Widgets, now is very large code.

This is my code:

```
            GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              isSelected = true;
              selectedId = list[index].id;
            },
            child: Obx(
              () {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  child: selectedId == list[index].id
                      ? Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border:
                                    Border.all(width: 2, color: 
                                    Colors.red),
                              ),
```

I'm using this in a separated widget.
I'm trying to re-use the widget. And sometimes can be same ID

I'm using Getx

Comment: use different id. can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same error

Comment: can you provide code

Comment: Now you can see my code.